# Let $a_n$ be the sequence defined inductively by $a_1 = 2$ and $a_{n+1} =(1/2)(a_n+2/a_n)$. Prove that $(a_n)^2 ⩾ 2$ for $n ∈ N$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, upper-lower-bounds

- I have already shown that $a_{n} \in \left[1, 2\right]\ \forall\, n \in \mathbb{N}$.
- I've also been told to start the proof by assuming $a_{n} < 2$ and finding a contradiction but I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Hvae you tried writing out $(a_{n + 1})^2$ fully?

Comment: square the recurrence

Comment: I did that and ended up with $(a_(n+1))^2 = (1/4)((a_n)^2 + 4 + 4/(a_n)^2)$  and i know that $(a_n)^2$ implies $4/(a_n)^2 > 2$ but im not sure how that helps me

Comment: The way to write $a_{n+1}$ is `a_{n+1}`.  Use braces, not parentheses.

Comment: apologies Robert mate thank you for letting me know

Comment: From $\tt Mathematica$, $a_{n} = \,\sqrt{\,{2}\,}\coth\left(2^{n - 1}\,\operatorname{arccoth}\left(\,\sqrt{\,{2}\,}\right)\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Proof via induction. Basis case: $a_1 > \sqrt{2}.$

Induction case: Using AM-GM, $a_n > 2 \implies a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + \frac{2}{a_n}}{2} > \sqrt{(a_n)\left( \frac{2}{a_n} \right)} = \sqrt{2}. $

Comment: We don't *need* to write it as strict inequality with AM-GM here. I just read that for AM-GM, "If every number in the list is the same, only then there is a possibility that two means are equal." I found this interesting, so left the strict inequality in. But like I say it's not necessary to write strict inequality here.

Answer (score 0):

We'll proceed by induction in order to prove that for the sequence defined by $a_{n+1} = \left(a_n + \frac{2}{a_n}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2}, a_1 = 2$, we have $(a_n)^2 \geq 2$ for all $n$.
We'll first check the base case, and then assume the property holds for $n = k$ to prove it for $n = k+1$.

*1-Base Case (n=1)*
For $a_1 = 2$, we have:
$ (a_1)^2 = 2^2 = 4 \geq 2 $ So, the base case holds.

*2- Assumption of the Induction*
Assume for some $k \geq 1$, $(a_k)^2 \geq 2$.

*3- Inductive Step*
Given: $ a_{k+1} = \left(a_k + \frac{2}{a_k}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2} $ we need to show that $(a_{k+1})^2 \geq 2$.
Let's express $(a_{k+1})^2$ and show it satisfies $(a_{k+1})^2 \geq 2$:
$(a_{k+1})^2 = \left(\left(a_k + \frac{2}{a_k}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}\left(a_k^2 + 4 + \frac{4}{a_k^2}\right) = \frac{(a_k^2 + 2)^2}{4a_k^2}$
Now it lets us to prove that $(a_{k+1})^2 \geq 2$. This is a case, indeed the following inequalities are verify:
$\frac{(a_k^2 + 2)^2}{4a_k^2} \geq 2 \Leftrightarrow (a_k^2 + 2)^2 = a_k^4 + 4 + 4a_k^2 \geq 8 a_k^2 \Leftrightarrow a_k^4 + 4 - 4a_k^2 \geq 2^2 + 4 - 4 \cdot 2 =0$
When the last inequality came from the fact that $a_k^2 \geq 2 $ by the assumption of the induction.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to show that the function $f(x)=x+2/x$ has minimum value $2\sqrt2$ for $x>0$;  hence $a_{n}$ has minimum value $\sqrt2$ for all $n$

Answer (score 0):

You have $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n^2+2}{2a_n}$ and $a_2=\dfrac32$ so $a_2^2\gt2$.

Consider tha function $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2+2}{2x}$. It is easy to verify that $f'(x)=\dfrac{x^2-2}{2x^2}\gt0$ when $x\gt2$ so it is increasing for $x\gt2$ (in fact for $x\gt\sqrt2$. Since $a_2^2\gt2$ we have $a_n^2\ge2$